# Bind @State to optional @Binding in the same struct SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, option-type

I am creating a View that may or may not receive a binding:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct AssignmentEditMenu: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var planner: Planner
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var isEditing // set to true if assignment is not nil
    var assignment: Binding<Assignment>?
        
    @State var newAssignment = assignment ?? Assignment()
    // if assignment is not nil, create a copy of it and set newAssignment equal to the copy
    // if assignment is nil, initialize a new struct and set newAssignment equal to it
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                nameSection
                dateSection
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("New Assignment"))
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(isEditing ? "Add" : "Done") {
                        isEditing ? (assignment = newAssignment) : planner.addAssignment(newAssignment)
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    var nameSection: some View {
        Section {
            TextField("Name", text: $newAssignment.name)
            Picker("Course", selection: $newAssignment.course) {
                ForEach(planner.courses) { course in
                    Text("\(course.name)").tag(course)
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    var dateSection: some View {
        Section {
            DatePicker(
                selection: $newAssignment.assignedDate,
                displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute]
            ) {
                Text("Assigned:")
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .allowsTightening(true)
            }
            DatePicker(
                selection: $newAssignment.dueDate
            ) {
                Text("Due:")
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .allowsTightening(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is if a binding to an `Assignment` is passed in here, then the View is in Edit Mode. `newAssignment` will be set to the same values as the `assignment` binding but not reference it at all. It will collect changes and when complete, set that `assignment` binding equal to itself, thus saving the changes. The reason for using `newAssignment` is so that if the user cancels (this view will be a sheet) changes are discarded since `newAssignment` is a @State var.

When no `Assignment` binding is passed in the View is in Create mode. `newAssignment` collects the changes and is added to the store via `planner`.

`Assignment` implementation:

```swift
struct Assignment: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable  {
    var name: String
    var assignedDate: Date
    var dueDate: Date
    var course: Course
    var percentCompleted: Double
    let id: UUID
    
    init(
        name: String = "",
        assignedDate: Date = Date(),
        dueDate: Date = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: .init(hour: 0, minute: 0), matchingPolicy: .strict)!,
        course: Course = Course()
    ) {
        self.name = name
        self.assignedDate = assignedDate
        self.dueDate = dueDate
        self.course = course
        self.id = UUID()
        self.percentCompleted = 0.0
    }
}

struct Course: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
    var name: String
    let id: UUID
    
    init(_ name: String = "Course") {
        self.name = name
        self.id = UUID()
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using an optional binding, why not using a normal binding and pass `.constant(Assignment())` when you need to create a new one? Or, you can create `Assignment` as an entity in Core Data: in this way, you don't need a binding, just create an `init()` method with optional `Assignment?`, the method that will either use the instance received or create a new one (Core Data publishes the changes).

Comment: You have an `EnvironmentObject` that contains all of your assignments. Why not leverage that? Your assignment is identifiable. Also, I think your data model is wrong. Your `Assignments` have `Courses`, but shouldn't the `Courses` have `Assignments`? You can then pass in the `Assignment id` or nil. If it is nil, you make a new assignment. If not, you use the assignment in `Planner`. I also agree with the above comment. This would be best modeled in Core Data as appropriate bidirectional relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a custom init. With that, `newAssignment` var is also not needed.

```
struct AssignmentEditMenu: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var planner: Planner
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var isEditing // set to true if assignment is not nil

   var assignment: Binding<Assignment>
    
    init(a: Binding<Assignment> = .constant(Assignment())) {
        assignment = a 
    }

.....

}
```